# "Loud" and "loudly": how to use them?

Tags: word-choice, questions

- Which one should I use?

  1. Play music loud
  2. Play music loudly

     - I think "play music loudly" is right but "play music loud" is used more. Please tell me your opinion and the reason why you choose it. Thank you so much.
     - Maybe my grammar is wrong 'cause I'm not good at English

Comment: "Play loud music", not "play music loud"

Comment: @V0ight I searched on Google and saw "play music loud" is right. I heard in the lyrics of Florida's song - My house: "play that music too loud"

Comment: I suppose it is right, my mistake. I still prefer the latter and would use it unconditionally; the former just sounds *wrong* to my ears.

Comment: The reason *loudly* is the "more correct" option is that you can't use loud as an adverb in all contexts, e.g. "He was loud playing the music as he walked with his radio on his shoulders". It can only be *loudly* in this specific context. So be careful to understand this as English is a fickle language.

Comment: Related question, [loud, aloud, loudly?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/loud-aloud-loudly).

Comment: Either say, "I played loud music," or, "I played music loudly."  In the former, "loud" is an adjective that describes "music."  In the latter, "loudly" is an adverb that describes "played."  You would not say, "I played music loud."  In English, except in very few cases, we do not put an adjective after the noun it is to describe.  Whereas adverbs may appear just about anywhere in relation to the verb they describe, adjectives appear immediately *before* the noun they describe.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, adjectives are turned into adverbs by adding the -*ly* suffix to them.

But some words are used as both adjectives *and* adverbs, with no discernable difference in their form. For example,

1. I like *fast* cars. [**adjective**]
2. He drove *fast*. [**adverb**]
3. They played a *clean* game. [**adjective**]
4. They played *clean*. [**adverb**]

"Loud" is an example of a word that can be used as *both* an adjective *and* an adverb. For example, people say:

5. I like *loud* music. [**adjective**]
6. I play music *loud*. [**adverb**]

If you look at [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22played%20loud%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) google books search, you'll see plenty example of it being used as an adverb. Further, [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/loud) even lists it as an adverb.

But some people also use the clearly adverbial form "loudly", as in

7. I play music *loudly*. [**adverb**]

In conclusion, both "loud" and "loudly" can be used as adverbs. The choice is yours.

Comment: Thank for your help. I have always thought "loud" is used as an adjective.

Comment: It mostly is, but it can *also* be used as an adverb.

Comment: No, they are different. "A turned the music loud" means "to increase the volume". "A turned the music loudly" means A caused noise during the process.