# Adjectives used as adverbs

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

In the following sentences, adjectives are used as if they are adverbs.

The child listened to the story spellbound.

They left the party happy.

We wanted to choose some shoes but we left the shop undecided.

He came to the office annoyed.

Could you please elaborate this usage?

Comment: They are all adjectival predicative adjuncts in your examples, not adverbs.

Comment: Related : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/which-is-correct-drive-safe-or-drive-safely and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337662/loud-and-loudly-how-to-use-them/337663?noredirect=1#comment776079_337663

Comment: Why people downvote an interesting question like this? Sad, sad, sad.

Answer (score 2):

It is called secondary predicate. Most of your sentences are End-State Secondary Predicates.

Here is the link with more detailed explanations.

http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~kay/bcg/II-Pred.html